# How these norms are equivalent in an Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have $H$ an Hilbert Space and $L:(H,\left\| \cdot \right\|_1) \rightarrow (H,\left\| \cdot \right\|_2)$ linear and bijective; here $\left<x,y\right>_2:=\left<Lx,Ly\right>_1$ and so $\left \| x \right \|_2:=\left \| Lx \right \|_1$

Where can I find the proof of the following?  $$\left\| \cdot \right\|_1 \mbox{is equivalent to} \left\| \cdot \right\|_2 \leftrightarrow L \mbox{ is continuous}$$

Comment: What does $\langle Lx, Ly \rangle_1$ mean, actually? How is $\langle .,.\rangle_1$ even defined?

Comment: maybe now is better.

Comment: No, you still defined $\langle x,y\rangle_2$ using $\langle .,.\rangle_1$, without telling us what $\langle .,.\rangle_1$ actually is.

Comment: an inner product defined in $H$.. I don't know what tell you

Comment: But if $L$ is defined, and $\langle .,.\rangle_1$ and $\langle .,.\rangle_2$ is defined, then what exactly did you define when you said $$\langle x,y\rangle_2=\langle Lx, Ly\rangle_1?$$

Comment: But the second one is defined using the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\|.\|_1$ is equivalent to $\|.\|_2$ then there is a constant $C$ with $\|x\|_2 \leq C \|x\|_1$ for all $x \in H$ so we have
$$\|Lx\|_2 \leq C \|Lx\|_1 = C \|x\|_2 \leq C^2 \|x\|_1$$
for all $x \in H$ which implies that $L$ is continuous.

If $L$ is continuous then
$\|x\|_2 = \|Lx\|_1 \leq \|L\| \|x\|_1$
and
$\|x\|_1 = \|L^{-1} x\|_2 \leq \|L^{-1}\| \|x\|_2$. So the norms are equivalent.

Comment: where $\left \| L \right \|$ is the sup of $Lx$?

Comment: Why is $L^{-1}$ continuous if $L$ is continuous and bijective? I see it in finite dimensions, but why does this work in infinite dimensions?